# Vue: Extract CSS - Didn't get a result from child compiler

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to write a `vue` component library that will work in `nuxt` and `vue`.

The issue i was originally having was `document is not defined` when using `Extract CSS`. from reading, i understand the `css-loader` webpack settings need to be adjusted to use a different module (one that isnt using `document`).

I have downloaded(npm) the new webpack module(https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) and copied in the example code without any luck.

The below is an example of the error i get for every component

```
      error  in ./components/inputs/shared/desc.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=08898866&scoped=true&lang=css&
      Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
      ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
      Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler
      at childCompiler.runAsChild (B:\lib\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:159:23)
      at compile (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11)
      at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at compilation.seal.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32)
      at _promise0.then._result0 (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
      at runLoaders (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20)
      at B:\lib\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
      at B:\lib\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:20
      at context.callback (B:\lib\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
      at childCompiler.runAsChild (B:\lib\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:159:14)
      at compile (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11)
      at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at compilation.seal.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
      at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (B:\lib\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
      at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (B:\lib\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32)
```

I have been looking on the interweb for hours now and cannot seem to find a solution.

I have been looking at the `API Docs` https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/build-config.html#server-config and cannot seem to find something that works. Additionally i tied deleting `node_modules`

```
  //vue.config.js
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  outputDir: 'dist',
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    extract: true //false
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        ignoreOrder: false
      })
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

-- Edit--
Here is a copy of the repo: https://github.com/mjmnagy/vue-error-2020-08-26

The issue mentioned by @sugars suggest compiling the nuxt build process to create the library. However, this would ultimately effect how the build process is compiled for the overall nuxt application(which is not what is desired).INSTEAD, there is a component library written within the nuxt application (used to create pages for each component more readily). I believe the `vue.config.js` needs to amended to use the webpack plugin for ssr safe extraction. The problem is that every tutorial or document i have found does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you do not need to manually import mini-css-extract-plugin in the nuxt project, it has built-in a [extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin/).

> Using extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin under the hood, all your CSS will be extracted into separate files, usually one per component. This allows caching your CSS and JavaScript separately and is worth a try in case you have a lot of global or shared CSS.

You only need to configure the `build` properties in the `nuxt.config.js` file.

You may want to extract all your CSS to a single file. There is a workaround for this:

```js
export default {
 build: {
   extractCSS: true,
   optimization: {
     splitChunks: {
       cacheGroups: {
         styles: {
           name: 'styles',
           test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
           chunks: 'all',
           enforce: true
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

> **WARNING**: It is not recommended extracting everything into a single file. Extracting into multiple css files is better for caching and preload isolation. It can also improve page performance by downloading and resolving only those resources that are needed.

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with the nuxt.build process. Will this create the distrution files that i can put onto npm? as far as i am aware, the only process is the `vue-cli-service build`?

Comment: does the code above split the css into a single file as you suggest not to do? or is this separating them? thanks

Comment: see more details about [Extractcss](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extractcss)